# Site collection Access Denied

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, site-collection, content-database, access-denied

I get Access Denied while viewing asite collection from the browser.

I am site collection administrator and I can open an other site collection in the same content DB

I can do `Get-SPSite` from PowerShell, I tried to do `iisreset` (and also to restart the server).

Where the problem can be?

In the log I see this error:

> Failure while fetching document

Comment: Is it publishing site? check from your central admin, if site is marked as locked? what type of authentication you are using? Close all browser and reopen it? try with different user ( make him as site collction admin from central admin) then try it.

Comment: yes It s a publishing site. It is not locked. I am using Claim auth. I migrate a SP10 content db on that web application, I guess the problem is there

Comment: What about Object Cache Setting on the Web app as this is publishing portal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was quite strange. 
My user account was twice in the `web.SiteUsers` set.
Once with the claims authentication `i:0#.w|domainname\username` and an other with classic authentication `domainname\username`.
I remove those users and then it worked fine.

I think I had this issue during the migration of the contentdb' users. (from 2010 to 2013)

Answer (score 0):

Is it something on the home page?

Here's a quick test: navigate to (site collection url)/_layouts/settings.aspx

Comment: still AccessDenied. If I add the user to the User Policy for that application it works fine. But do not know why